# how to use openie from stanford-corenlp without using lemma from stanford-corenlp?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want to see if results would improve if we use our own lemma analysis.
But pipeline requires lemma before annotation.

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MorphaAnnotator you can see how lemmas are added to an annotation in the Java code.

You can create your own custom annotator that supplies your lemmas based off that code.

I've needed to update our documentation about custom annotators, so I've actually written a detailed version of the CustomLemmaAnnotator and supplied it on our documentation site.

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/new_annotator.html

Comment: what if I want to get rid of CoreNLP framework?  We defined a set of data structure to fit our system.